# Retrofit 2 returns null on its member variables

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm currently studying retrofit 2 and came across with a problem.

I'm using a free api

```
http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all
```

Here are my POJOs

RestResponse

```
public class RestResponse {

    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private List<String> messages;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result;

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Result

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("alpha2_code")
    @Expose
    private String alpha2Code;
    @SerializedName("alpha3_code")
    @Expose
    private String alpha3Code;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAlpha2Code() {
        return alpha2Code;
    }

    public void setAlpha2Code(String alpha2Code) {
        this.alpha2Code = alpha2Code;
    }

    public String getAlpha3Code() {
        return alpha3Code;
    }

    public void setAlpha3Code(String alpha3Code) {
        this.alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("country/get/all")
    Call<RestResponse> getCountry();

}
```

MainActivity

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getmRetrofitClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<RestResponse> call = apiService.getCountry();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RestResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RestResponse> call, Response<RestResponse> response) {
                List<Result> results = response.body().getResult();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RestResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("onFailure", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

The retrofit calls the onResponse callback, but when I'm trying to get the result from the response.body() it returns null. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post you API response?

Comment: @Sonali8890 you can go http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all and see the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need a different class also for holding the `RestResponse`, because the Json response that you're getting has first level object `RestResponse` and then that one is the class that you have.

[image]

So you would need something like:

```
public class CountryResponse {

    @SerializedName("RestResponse")
    @Expose
    private RestResponse restResponse;

    public RestResponst getRestResponse() { return restResponse; }
    public void setRestResponse(RestResponse restResp) {restResponse = restResp; }
}
```

And you just need to change the API call line to:

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getmRetrofitClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call< CountryResponse > call = apiService.getCountry();
    call.enqueue(new Callback< CountryResponse >() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
            List<Result> results = response.body().getRestResponse().getResult();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call< CountryResponse > call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("onFailure", t.getMessage());
        }
});
```

Try this and this should work.